# TCP error in case wrong IP Address specified in WCF although the IP Address is correct

Tags: c#, wcf

I have application that host `WCF` service.
I am opening the connection via `BackgroundWorker`

```
private bool isConnected;
private BackgroundWorker asyncWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    InitializeComponent();        
    asyncWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    asyncWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    asyncWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                    (bwAsync_ProgressChanged);
    asyncWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
                    (bwAsync_RunWorkerCompleted);
    asyncWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bwAsync_DoWork);
    btnConnect.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
```

This is my Connect button click event:

```
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        Interface.interfaceNumber = interfaceNumber;
        asyncWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

And DoWork:

```
private void bwAsync_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bwAsync = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    try
    {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            // Returns a list of ipaddress configuration
            IPHostEntry ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            // Get machine ipaddress
            IPAddress _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(tbServerIp.Text);

            // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be started
            urlService = "net.tcp://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8000/MyService";

            // Instruct the ServiceHost that the type that is used is a ServiceLibrary.service1
            //host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.service1));
            ServiceLibrary.service1 serviceInstance = new ServiceLibrary.service1();
            serviceInstance.CapturingEvent += yourServiceInstance_StartCapturingEvent;
            serviceInstance.OnProcessExitedEvent += serviceInstance_OnProcessExitedEvent;
            host = new ServiceHost(serviceInstance);
            host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
            host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
            host.Closing += new EventHandler(host_Closing);
            host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);

            // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // <- Very crucial

            // Add a endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceLibrary.IService1), tcpBinding, urlService);

            // A channel to describe the service. Used with the proxy scvutil.exe tool
            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
            metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (metadataBehavior == null)
            {
                // Create the proxy object that is generated via the svcutil.exe tool
                metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://" + _ipAddress.ToString() + ":8001/MyService");
                metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                metadataBehavior.ToString();
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
                urlMeta = metadataBehavior.HttpGetUrl.ToString();
            }

            host.Open();
            isConnected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (asyncWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                //bnAsync.Enabled = false;
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblStatus.Text = "Cancelling..."; });

                // Notify the worker thread that a cancel has been requested.
                // The cancel will not actually happen until the thread in the
                // DoWork checks the bwAsync.CancellationPending flag, for this
                // reason we set the label to "Cancelling...", because we haven't
                // actually cancelled yet.
                asyncWorker.CancelAsync();
            }

            host.Close();
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Lock\Release buttons
}
```

My application connect successfully and all works fine but in case i am specified wrong IP Address i get TCP error that `requested Ip Address is not valid` which is OK but in case i fix this wrong IP Address to the correct Ip Address i still get the same error unless my application is restarted.
Maybe my thread is still running and this is why i cannot connect ?

Answer (score 2):

First off don't use IP addresses unless your just doing `localhost` dev, it's always a bad idea, use DNS names or hosts file name entries. Secondly, I assume that your `host` variable is a class member variable (code you didn't include above). After you open the host, it's bindings are going to remain active in server memory until you restart the application which is standard practice.

The other issue with that code is that in the `else` block of `bwAsync_DoWork` you close the host after the form button is clicked but you are not re-binding/re-opening the host with the updated form data. Consider doing the following to fix this.

1. Move the code that does the actual host binding out of `bwAsync_DoWork` into its own method.
2. Call this method at the very end of `bwAsync_DoWork` to ensure the new binding is turned on.

code:

```
private void bwAsync_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bwAsync = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if (asyncWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lblStatus.Text = "Cancelling..."; });

        asyncWorker.CancelAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        if(isConnected)
        {
            host.Close();
            isConnected = false;
        }   
        BindHost();         
    }
}


private void BindHost() 
{
    ...
    isConnected = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me please how to use DNS names or hosts file name entries ?

Comment: BTW i still received the same error after insert wrong ip address and reinsert the correct one